# Runtime Context Links to wrong output type

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

It seems that the `ProcessFunction` class' `context` is looking for a `flink.util.OutputTag` output tag for it's `context.output()` function instead of a `streaming.api.scala.OutputTag`. and `DataStream.getSideOutput()` is looking for a `streaming.api.scala.OutputTag`

Sample code of mine:

```
val outputTag  = OutputTag[(String, Long, Long)]("output")
//Stuff
.process {
  new ProcessFunction[(String, Long), (String, Long, Long)] {
    lazy val state: ValueState[Event] = getRuntimeContext.getState(new ValueStateDescriptor[Event]("stats", classOf[Event]))

      override def processElement(value: (String, Long), ctx: ProcessFunction[(String, Long), (String, Long, Long)]#Context, out: Collector[(String, Long, Long)]) {
        val current: Event = state.value() match {
          case null =>
            Event(value._1, 1, value._2)
          case Event(key, count, total) =>
            Event(key, count + 1, totalTos + value._2)
        }

        state.update(current)

        ctx.output(outputTag, (current.key, current.count, current.total))
      }
    }
  }    
  val  sideOutputStream: DataStream[(String, Long, Long)] = mainDataStream.getSideOutput(outputTag)
```

The Error:

```
Error:(55, 24) type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.OutputTag[(String, Long, Long)]
required: org.apache.flink.util.OutputTag[(String, Long, AnyVal)]
Note: (String, Long, Long) <: (String, Long, AnyVal), but Java-defined class 
OutputTag is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: (String, Long, 
AnyVal)`. (SLS 3.2.10)
```

I am using Flink 1.3.2, Scala 2.11.  Is there anyway to get the Flink Side ouput example(Found: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/side_output.html ) to work correctly in Scala using 1.3.2?

Comment: What's the type of  `current.total`? You can try and append an explicit `.toLong` to force the type checker. Does that help?

Comment: This was the problem, it was a Float, should have been a Long